# TLS handshake to microsoft.com hangs

Tags: networking, https, tls, pcap

Two Linux machines (Ubuntu 20.04 & 18.04.4 running on vSphere) behind NAT are not able to complete the TLS handshake to `https://microsoft.com` and `https://mcr.microsoft.com`, while they are able to connect to `https://docs.microsoft.com` and other websites. I manage the firewall and NAT myself (virtual VyOS router). Another system behind the same NAT is able to access `https://microsoft.com`. I already tried to update all packages, and used `curl --resolve` to try different Microsoft IPs.

I found this when trying to use the container registry:

```
 Pulling docker image mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: Get https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/: net/http: TLS handshake timeout (executor_docker.go:188:10s)

curl -i https://docs.microsoft.com
HTTP/2 301
location: /en-us/
(...)

curl -i http://microsoft.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
(...)

curl -vv https://microsoft.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://microsoft.com/
*   Trying 104.215.148.63...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to microsoft.com (104.215.148.63) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
^C
```

Debugging with openssl shows that it hangs.

```
openssl s_client -connect microsoft.com:443 -debug
CONNECTED(00000003)
write to 0x563308e92000 [0x563308ea2500] (305 bytes => 305 (0x131))
0000 - 16 03 01 01 2c 01 00 01-28 03 03 68 a0 18 e1 33   ....,...(..h...3
0010 - 14 d3 6f ef 02 17 72 c0-8e fd 4a 94 bd 03 38 ba   ..o...r...J...8.
0020 - 7b b3 91 a0 67 6c 85 94-e8 2b fb 20 a6 15 74 4c   {...gl...+. ..tL
0030 - 8c 8a 3f e8 31 05 a1 0d-f5 65 dc 70 f9 96 b0 03   ..?.1....e.p....
0040 - 33 32 12 32 1e 72 29 0f-ef 30 80 19 00 3e 13 02   32.2.r)..0...>..
0050 - 13 03 13 01 c0 2c c0 30-00 9f cc a9 cc a8 cc aa   .....,.0........
0060 - c0 2b c0 2f 00 9e c0 24-c0 28 00 6b c0 23 c0 27   .+./...$.(.k.#.'
0070 - 00 67 c0 0a c0 14 00 39-c0 09 c0 13 00 33 00 9d   .g.....9.....3..
0080 - 00 9c 00 3d 00 3c 00 35-00 2f 00 ff 01 00 00 a1   ...=.<.5./......
0090 - 00 00 00 12 00 10 00 00-0d 6d 69 63 72 6f 73 6f   .........microso
00a0 - 66 74 2e 63 6f 6d 00 0b-00 04 03 00 01 02 00 0a   ft.com..........
00b0 - 00 0c 00 0a 00 1d 00 17-00 1e 00 19 00 18 00 23   ...............#
00c0 - 00 00 00 16 00 00 00 17-00 00 00 0d 00 2a 00 28   .............*.(
00d0 - 04 03 05 03 06 03 08 07-08 08 08 09 08 0a 08 0b   ................
00e0 - 08 04 08 05 08 06 04 01-05 01 06 01 03 03 03 01   ................
00f0 - 03 02 04 02 05 02 06 02-00 2b 00 05 04 03 04 03   .........+......
0100 - 03 00 2d 00 02 01 01 00-33 00 26 00 24 00 1d 00   ..-.....3.&.$...
0110 - 20 ce b9 90 2d 17 37 38-46 47 83 cd 06 b5 82 25    ...-.78FG.....%
0120 - 91 ee c1 5a d5 e2 53 62-26 6d 19 59 48 c8 f0 2f   ...Z..Sb&m.YH../
0130 - 6f                                                o
# Here it hangs for a few minutes
^C
```

Meanwhile I ran `tcpdump 'host microsoft.com'`, [see this WireShark view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GA5Z.png).

What can I do to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Configuring TCP-MSS Clamping](https://docs.vyos.io/en/latest/routing/mss-clamp.html) in the VyOS firewall solves the problem.
I suppose the WireGuard tunnel makes the maximum segment size smaller, causing PMTU discovery to fail.

```sh
set firewall options interface wg02 adjust-mss '1372'
```

This [link](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1478704) is a related question with an pppoe interface. That discussion helped me to find the solution.